# How to have jtables values which are strings in alphabetical order using comparator and tablerowsorter?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, comparator

the title says it clearly. I wanted to use quicksort algorithm but one of my friends said that I could use comparator but i don't know how to.

Comment: Did you read [How to use tables - sorting and filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)?

Comment: Yes and i tried that but i doesn't seems to work
http://pastebin.com/4s6B4HBC

Comment: Then you should provide the code you used - please do not copy all code but make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must create a comparator:

```
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
         return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
};
```

With this comparator you will be able to sort your data in alphabetical order.

After that create sorter and pass this comparator and model of your JTable.

Then:

```
sorter.sort();
```

I think after that your data will be sorted.

Comment: Ok thanks. apparently I can't vote up because I don't enough reputation

Comment: -1, There is no need to create a custom Comparator. JTable will sort column automatically when you add the RowSorter assuming your getColumnClass() method is implemented correctly. This answer may work but it is reinventing the wheel. There is still some other problem with the code.

Comment: @camickr, please, carefully read question title. I think "using comparator" means that user2397207 wants to sort data using custom comparator:)

Comment: @pbespechnyi, The OP is sure what he is doing. He was going to write his own sorting code when a friend suggested a Comparator can be used. The requirement is to sort String in order. You don't need a custom Comparator to do that. There is no need to reinvent the wheel.